# IMAP: How to send additional command text

Tags: imap

I'm sending the followed command to IMAP server:

```
A0003 SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 HEADER SUBJECT {8}\r\nТЕСТ
```

and response is

```
+ Ready for additional command text.
```

What should I send for completing first command?

Comment: {8} means that CRLF, eight bytes and another CRLF are coming. TECT is four bytes and your question contains one CRLF. Please clarify.

Comment: @arnt here is cyrillic chars, so it takes 2 bytes per char

Comment: My bad. Sorry. I should've guessed. Try sending \r\n after the ТЕСТ, the server may be waiting for that. There is also another minor issue: Strictly speaking, {8} means that you have to wait for the server's permission ("+") to go ahead. But I doubt that many servers actually enforce that wait.

Comment: @arnt I send `NOOP\r\n` without marker, but not sure this is correct

Comment: NOOP doesn't take any arguments. `{8}\r\nТЕСТ` is a string argument, so `A0003 SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 HEADER SUBJECT {8}\r\nТЕСТ` is an almost-complete command, which lacks only the `\r\n` that terminates the command.